# Alpine on WSL2 - `apk update` and `apk add` not working

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, alpine-linux, wsl-2

I am running Alpine 3.17.0 on Windows WSL2 (Windows 10, OS Build 19045.3930)

While my `apk` and `apk list` commands work fine, I cannot run `apk update`, nor can I `apk add` any package (example, `apk add nano`)

For all of these commands, I get the following error:

`ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied`

`sudo apk add` also doesn't work.

I have removed and installed the distro several times and each time this error is the same. According to the installation logs everything is installing properly.

How do I get access to the `apk update` and `apk add` commands?

Comment: On — most of — the linux distributions, you have to be root (or sudo) in order to install a package.